# Deleted question as a known good audit in close vote review?

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, review, review-audits

Hitting the close vote reviews, I came across [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/close/82286).

> [image: screen shot of review]

I'm really not sure what the proper action on it is.  It's been deleted. I'm not sure if I should leave it open (it's deleted), close it (it's deleted), or attempt to edit it (it's deleted).  So... why was this one of the reviews that showed up?

I hit skip.  And I suspect its not an audit.  So, is there something amiss with the 'our system has identified this post as possible spam' system?

Comment: Same here on what I did.

Comment: maybe because it was [cross posted to gamedev.SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/86598/28905) before Robert deleted it?

Comment: @ratchetfreak I kind of doubt it.  I would *love* it if multi-site cross posting would get flagged in such a way and if thats the answer, then it could be a good thing... thigh there are still issues with the 'how does one complete this review reasonably?'

Comment: just stumbled over that funny item. It _is_ an audit because system tries to trick me by hiding real score of the post (it shows 0 while my magic 10K powers show it's +6/-0 and there are no close votes there). Okay I am going to test what happens if I pick Leave Open (if it wasn't deleted, that would be what I do in audits like that)...

Comment: ...okay, [Leave Open passed the audit](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/review/close/82286) (as if I care about pass/fail here). Gotta flag the question for mod attention because SE team doesn't seem to give a sh!t about meta report